# overloading template function

Tags: c++

Currently, I encounter some difficulty in overloading a certain function. here's my code:

```
template<typename Value>
bool process(Value thisValue)
{
  return processAccordingToTheType(thisValue);
}
```

So, there are two overloaded function of processAccordingToTheType:

```
bool processAccordingToTheType(int thisValue){}
bool processAccordingToTheType(string thisValue){}
```

when I try to compile it, it said:

```
error C2665: 'processAccordingToTheType' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

what do I need to do?

Update:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 1;
  process <int> (i);
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking your function?

Comment: This should work if you don't call `process` with something other than int or string (or something that converts to one of these).

Comment: @jrok when I tried to compile it, I got that error message

Comment: Please show the code where you _call_ process, and how the argument is declared

Comment: @StoviaSmith Then please provide a small compilable test case, so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Are you including the `<string>` header? Do you have a `using std::string` declaration? Your code seems to compile [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz$55), once you include those.

Comment: @andyprowl Yeah. I've include <string> and "using namespace std"

Comment: How old is your compiler, btw?

Comment: @StoviaSmith: Is your code any different from the one I linked?

Comment: @andyprowl I copy paste ur code, and I got the same error

Comment: @StoviaSmith: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @andyprowl I'm not sure, how can I check it? I'm using visual c++ 2008

Comment: @andyprowl I just compile my code in gcc and it works just fine. do you think there's any problem w/ my visual c++ compiler?

Comment: @StoviaSmith: I believe so, but I can't guess what the root cause is

Answer (score 3):

From your sample code I understand you need two things to be done:

1. Call a type specific `process` function
2. Restrict these calls to `string` and `int` types

Wrapping the `processAccordingToType` function inside `process<T>` is completely redundant: `process<T>` actually means 'process according to type'. The keyword here is 'template specialization'. You need to specialize your 'process according to type' method for `int` and `string`.

You can do this as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool process(T t)
{
    // call a Compile-Time Assertion 
    cout << "I don't want this to be called." << endl;
}

template <>
bool process<int>(int i)
{
    cout << "process(int) called." << endl;
}


template <>
bool process<string>(string s)
{
    cout << "process(string) called." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    process(1);
    process(string("s"));
    process(1.0d);
}
```

Output:

```
process(int) called.
process(string) called.
I don't want this to be called.
```

Ideally, you want to prevent the users of your API calling `process` with other types. Allowing them to call and handling this at runtime (like it's done in my example) is not acceptable. You achieve this with Compile-Time Assertions. Read "Modern C++ Designs" by Andrei Alexandrescu for ways of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Look into template specialization. Does what you're looking for without deferring to another function based on type.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can overload function templates with either a non-template function or another template function.  Make sure that whatever you do, you test incrementally as template errors are notoriously hard to understand.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename Value>
bool processAccordingToTheType( Value thisValue ){
    cout << "Generic Type" << endl;
    return false;
}

bool processAccordingToTheType(int thisValue){
    cout << "int type" << endl;
    return true;
}

template <typename Value>
bool process( Value thisValue ){
    return processAccordingToTheType(thisValue);
} 

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){

    cout << process( 1 ) << endl;
    cout << process( "Hello" ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I required to declare the processAccordingToTheType function for generic type?

Comment: No, you're not. As long as you don't try to invoke a non-existing overload, you should be fine.